# Which Java configuration property helps me to display all the records in a topic from the beginning ( offset 0)

Tags: java, apache-kafka

```java
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "mygroup");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"");

// earliest --> for consuming from nth offset where (n-1)th offset record is the last record consumer consumed before shitting down

// latest --> for consuming the records that are generated after consumer has started to consume
```

Is there is any way that sets the offset to 0 and start consuming from the beginning?

If you want to check my code here are my gist links:

- [MyKafkaProducer.java](https://gist.github.com/immrdg/71160d3346b3b436cc1bf5eb6e90546b)
- [MyKafkaConsumer.java](https://gist.github.com/immrdg/5d8eb8a879a2f2230c6edfa2e863e63b)

I tried placing these lines before while loop, but it didn't work.

```java
consumer.poll(Duration.ZERO); 
consumer.seekToBeginning(consumer.assignment());
```

I just want to make a code that does this task

```bash
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic myjson --from-beginning
```

Let me know in the comment section if you don't get my question.

Comment: Your code with consumer.seekToBeginning looks good. Why exactly it didn't work? Please add log output of the consumer with and without this line consumer.seekToBeginning(consumer.assignment()); Just to be sure - the line is after consumer.subscribe, right?

Comment: @Mar-Z .. I'm not getting logs its only consuming earliest messages

Answer (score 0):

```
private void adjustOffset(KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer) {
    Set<TopicPartition> assignments = consumer.assignment();
    switch (ConfAttr.KAFKA_OFFSET_ADJUST_TYPE) {
        case "0":
            break;
        case "1":
            assignments.forEach(topicPartition ->
                    consumer.seekToBeginning(
                            Arrays.asList(topicPartition)));
            break;
        case "2":
            assignments.forEach(topicPartition ->
                    consumer.seek(
                            topicPartition,
                            Integer.parseInt(ConfAttr.KAFKA_OFFSET_ADJUST_VALUE)));
            break;
        case "3":
            Map<TopicPartition, Long> query = new HashMap<>();
            for (TopicPartition topicPartition : assignments) {
                query.put(
                        topicPartition,
                        Instant.now().minus(Integer.parseInt(ConfAttr.KAFKA_OFFSET_ADJUST_VALUE), MINUTES).toEpochMilli());
            }

            Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> result = consumer.offsetsForTimes(query);

            result.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .forEach(entry ->
                            consumer.seek(
                                    entry.getKey(),
                                    Optional.ofNullable(entry.getValue())
                                            .map(OffsetAndTimestamp::offset)
                                            .orElse(new Long(0))));

    }
    adjustOffsetFlag = false;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: think about offset is at  Partition

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).